# Showing that matrix $Q=UV^T$ is the nearest orthogonal matrix to $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, orthogonal-matrices, procrustes-problem

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with a singular value decomposition $A=U\Sigma V^T$. Show that the matrix $Q=UV^T$ is the nearest orthogonal matrix to $A$, i.e.,

$$\min_{Q^TQ=I_{n \times n}} \|A-Q\|_F$$

Comment: If $A$ is $m\times n$, then also $UV^T$ is $m\times n$. So, I guess it is assumed that $m = n$?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I think he meant to say that $m>n$ and that $Q$ is orthogonal on the rows (such that $Q'Q$ is identity).

Comment: The solution when $n=m$ has been stated below. For the most general case where A is not even full-column rank, this paper proved the statement:
 https://doi.org/10.1007%2FBF02289451

Answer (score 16):

*Note that, as stated, the question only makes sense if $n=m$, because in the singular value decomposition of $A$, $U$ will be $m\times m$ and $V^T$ will be $n\times n$.*

Because the Frobenius norm is unitarily invariant, you have 
$$
\|A-Q\|_F=\|U\Sigma V^T-Q\|_F=\|\Sigma-U^TQV\|_F.
$$
But the orthogonal (or the unitary) matrices form a group, so you want to minimize
$$
\|\Sigma-Q\|_F
$$
over all orthogonal matrices. You have 
\begin{align}
\|\Sigma-Q\|_F^2&=\sum_k(\Sigma_{kk}-Q_{kk})^2+\sum_{j\ne k}Q_{kj}^2\\ \ \\
&=\sum_k(\Sigma_{kk}^2+Q_{kk}^2-2\Sigma_{kk}Q_{kk})+\sum_{j\ne k}Q_{kj}^2\\ \ \\
&=\sum_k(\Sigma_{kk}^2-2\Sigma_{kk}Q_{kk})+\sum_{j,k}Q_{kj}^2\\ \ \\
&=\text{Tr}(\Sigma^2)+\text{Tr}(Q^TQ)-2\sum_k\Sigma_{kk}Q_{kk}\\ \ \\
&=\text{Tr}(\Sigma^2)+n-2\sum_k\Sigma_{kk}Q_{kk}
\end{align}
To minimize this quantity over $Q$, since the entries of $\Sigma$ are non-negative and $Q_{kk}\in[-1,1]$, we need to choose $Q_{kk}=1$ for all $k$, which makes $Q=I$.

So the minimum is 
$$
\|\Sigma-I\|_F=\|U\Sigma V^T-UV^T\|_F=\|A-UV^T\|_F.
$$

Comment: It is $Tr(\Sigma^2)$, not $Tr(\Sigma)$. It should also be $\|\Sigma-Q\|_F^2$ with square.

Comment: Indeed! Editing.

Comment: Some SVD formulas are based on ${U}$ being ${m}$x${q}$, $\Lambda$ being ${q}$x${q}$ where ${q}$ is the number of positive singular values, and ${V^T}$ being ${q}$x${n}$, so the original question can perhaps go through if we just assume orthonormal columns for ${UV^T}$.

Comment: The original question does make sense when $m>n$.

Comment: I'd just like to reiterate Carlos' statement that the original question does make sense when $m > n$ (using a reduced SVD). Theorem 4 of Sparse Principal Component Analysis by Zhou, Hastie and Tibshirani give the required result when $m > n$. The proof on the wikipedia page for Orthogonal Procrustes problem also works.