# Prove that $UV^T$ is the nearest orthogonal matrix to $A$ given $||A||=\max_{x\neq 0}\dfrac{||Ax||}{||x||}=\sigma_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, orthogonal-matrices

> Prove that $UV^T$ is the nearest orthogonal matrix to $A$
> ie., $||A-Q||\geq ||A-UV^T||$ for all orthogonal matrices $Q$
> given the norm of the matrix is defined as $||A||=\max_{x\neq 0}\dfrac{||Ax||}{||x||}=\sigma_1$

The SVD of $A$ is $A=U\Sigma V^T=\sum_{i=1}^{r}\sigma_i u_i v_i^T$

$$
||A-Q||=||U\Sigma V^T-Q||=||U^T\Big(U\Sigma V^T-Q\Big)V||=||\Sigma-U^TQV||=||\Sigma-Q'||
$$

So we need to solve for $Q'$ when $||\Sigma-Q'||$ is minimized for the orthogonal matrix $Q'$.

How do I prove it ?

**Note:**

Similar question has been asked at [Showing that matrix $Q=UV^T$ is the nearest orthogonal matrix to A.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215359/showing-that-matrix-q-uvt-is-the-nearest-orthogonal-matrix-to-a), but it is for the Frobenius norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{aligned}
\|\Sigma-Q'\|
&=\max_{\|u\|=1}\|\Sigma u-Q'u\|\\
&\ge\max_{\|u\|=1}\big|\,\|\Sigma u\|-\|Q'u\|\,\big|\\
&=\max_{\|u\|=1}\big|\,\|\Sigma u\|-1\,\big|\\
&=\max(|\sigma_1-1|,|\sigma_n-1|)\\
&=\|\Sigma-I\|.
\end{aligned}