# Unitary matrix corruption

Tags: matrices, unitary-matrices, noise

Suppose I have got a unitary matrix and I want to introduce random noise to simulate data corruption. How to introduce the noise in a proper way such that the corrupted matrix is also unitary?

Comment: Hi, Marina, what have you tried on it ? Can you further precise the range of your study especially the size of your matrix and the context in general ?

Comment: @EDX, hi! Actually I try do find information and did not try anything. Except naively add noise matrix to the unitary matrix. But then corrupteed matrix is not unitry anymore. The matrix can be of size 2x2, 4x4, 8x8, 16x16... So, any power of 2.

Comment: You may now have what is essentially a coupled system, comprising your original system embedded in a noise bath. It may be that you need to extend your unitary to this whole system so that you have a unitary there but not necessarily on the original system? My thoughts are only vague on this though!

Comment: @Paul I'm afraid I did not uunderstand you correctly, but originally I have a unitary matrix. But it is ideal matrix. I need to corrupt it such that the "unitariness" preserves, but values are shifted.

Comment: Never mind, I did say vague! The answer below probably covers what you want.

Comment: another approach would be to use any standard corruption scheme (such as additive noise) then to project the resulting matrix onto the set of unitary ones.

Comment: @JohnMadden How would one perform this projection? Could you point me to a reference?

Comment: @JohnMadden Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Sorry for too many comments. Found something relevant here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215359/showing-that-matrix-q-uvt-is-the-nearest-orthogonal-matrix-to-a

Answer (score 3):

If I may sum up your problem :

You have an unitary matrix $U$ enventually complex so $U^*U=UU^*=I$

So if we introduce a multiplicative noise $N$ such that the resulting signal is $U'=NU$.

Then if we required $U'$ to be unitary :

$$U^*N^*NU=NUU^*N^*=I $$

Second term implies $NN^*=I$. It is sufficient so to take $N$ such as $N^*N=I$

Then it is sufficient to take a multiplicative noise which is unitary.

Then using this paper https://case.edu/artsci/math/esmeckes/Meckes_SAMSI_Lecture2.pdf can give you idea on how to practically generate it.