# Optimal orthogonal transformation - the naive way

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, orthogonality

**I am solving the following problem:**

For given position vectors $\vec{x}_1,...,\vec{x}_n$ and $\vec{y}_1,...,\vec{y}_n$ we have following equations

$Q\vec{x}_i+\vec{b}=\vec{y}_i$, $i=1,...,n$

$Q^TQ=I$

with unknowns

$ Q=
\begin{bmatrix}
 q_{11} & q_{12} & ... &q_{1k}\\
 q_{21} & q_{22} & ... &q_{2k}\\
 ... & ... & ... & ...\\
 q_{k1} & q_{k2} & ... &q_{kk}
\end{bmatrix}
$
and
$b=\begin{bmatrix}
 b_{1}\\ 
 b_{2}\\
 ...\\
 b_{k}
\end{bmatrix}$

(This is a system of $kn+k^2$ equations for $k^2+k$ unknowns, where $k=\dim\mathbb{R}^k$.) The problem is that $k^2$ equations from $Q^TQ=I$ are not linear. The naive solution: We ignore equality $Q^TQ=I$ and are left with $kn$ equations for $k^2+k$ unknowns:

$Q\vec{x}_i+\vec{b}=\vec{y}_i$, $i=1,...,n$

We assume that $n\geq 2k$ so that we get an overdetermined system of linear equations.

Task: Write down the matrix of this system and find the solution of the system, matrix $Q'$ and vector $b$ by least squares method. Because $Q'$ is not necessarily orthogonal, we correct it by taking $Q$ from QR decomposition $Q'=QR$. The solution to the problem are now matrix $Q$ and vector $b$

My solving:

$Q\vec{x}_i+\vec{b}=\vec{y}_i$ is equal to $\vec{x}_{i}^TQ^T + \vec{b}^T=\vec{y}_i^T$

For $n=3$ the system of equations looks like

$
\begin{bmatrix}
 \vec{x}_{1}^TQ^T + \vec{b}^T\\
 \vec{x}_{2}^TQ^T + \vec{b}^T\\
 \vec{x}_{3}^TQ^T + \vec{b}^T\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \vec{y}_{1}^T\\
 \vec{y}_{2}^T\\
 \vec{y}_{3}^T\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

to put in in the form $Ax=b$

$
\begin{bmatrix}
 \vec{x}_{1}^T& 1\\ 
 \vec{x}_{2}^T& 1\\
 \vec{x}_{3}^T& 1
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
 Q^T\\ 
 \vec{b}^T
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \vec{y}_{1}^T\\ 
 \vec{y}_{2}^T\\
 \vec{y}_{3}^T
\end{bmatrix}
$

And then got $x=\begin{bmatrix}
 Q^T\\ 
 \vec{b}^T
\end{bmatrix}
$ by solving $A^TAx=A^Tb$

and from there got $b$ from the last row and $Q'$ from the other rows.

For $Q'\vec{x}_i+b=\vec{y}_i$ i get corrent solutions. But after getting corrected $Q$ from QR decomposition, i get wrong solutions from this equation when swapping $Q'$ with $Q$.

How am i supposed to represent the system of equations differently

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215359/showing-that-matrix-q-uvt-is-the-nearest-orthogonal-matrix-to-a might help?

Comment: I believe this is equivalent to the Orthogonal Procrustes problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem